# How does probability/stochastic theories change if we use nonstandard topology space on R?

Tags: probability, general-topology, measure-theory

I understand that in standard probability/stochastic theory we use the Borel algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ with its standard topology. I am wondering if there has been any study using a non-standard topology, and if so, what change/benefit does it bring intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

[Probability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory) deals with general (abstract) [probability spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space), which are defined axiomatically, independent on topology.